# Executing Unix Commands from Local in Python

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

I need to execute unix commands from my local in python. I can connect to the server and create files, however anytime I try to execute commands, I get no result on the server.

The path to the server is

```
path = "M:\\dir1\\dir2"
```

where M is a mapped windows network drive.

I can use `fh` to create a file and write to it, but then I need to change the permissions to executable and execute it in another call.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `os.chmod` as seen here https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod to change permissions

To execute you can use 
`subprocess.Popen(["executable_file"],  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: what about the further execution? Will sub.call work then?

Comment: What do you mean further execution?

Comment: I need to execute the file that I've changed the file on. This will launch a job on the unix machine and create file output that python from my local will retrieve once finished.